# Login with passeport node and angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm trying to build an angular 2 application,here is my backend implementation

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) return res.json(401, error);
    if (!user) return res.json(404, {message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'});

    var token = auth.signToken(user._id, user.role);
    res.json({token: token});
  })(req, res, next)
});
```

now i want to implement my frontend side with angular 2 but i have no idea how to code service and component.
any solution?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is exactly but have you read through the tutorial ? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/ . Front end assuming this is the ui is pretty basic and included in the tutorial. Tutorial is in typescript but the transition to js should be fairly easy

Comment: I suggest you start looking into the official ng2/ng4 tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html